# Is there a phrase like "you have right" meaning "you are right"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I use the phrase "you have right" quite often when I want to say that somebody is right about something. But today I was corrected that there is no such saying, and that "you have a right" can mean only that somebody has some rights to do something.

What is the truth?

Comment: If the dictionary says "to be right", you should believe it and that "to have right" (as in some other languages) is wrong.

Comment: "You have it right" might be used to mean "Yes, you understand it correctly".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct phrase for the action you're describing would be "You are right". "You have right" is not a valid English phrase, although "You have it right" would be understandable to an English speaker.

As you were correctly told, "You have a right" means that you are stating that someone has a right (To do something, to say something, to be something).

Answer (score 2):

To add to Robin's answer "you have the right of it" is an out-moded way of saying "you are right" but is almost never heard today.

Stick with "you *are* right".

Comment: +1 for mentioning "you have the right of it". Very occasionally I see it online and it grates.